# how to open print tab when user click button angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have print view and controller to print result when user click on link:
 `<a  data-ng-click="openPrintPreview(tab.countyID)">Employee List</a>`

I want to use ng click to open print preview windows and show the print controller but my problem is view the current page 'http://localhost/#/reception' not http://localhost/#/print/2

```
$scope.openPrintPreview = function(countyId){
     var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=700');
         popupWin.print('#/print/' + countyId);
};
```

Comment: I think you want `popupWin.print()`

Comment: Ok that open windows but wont load the http://localhost/#/print/2 the url is blank

Comment: Try replacing the first parameter of open with the URL you want to display in the popup and just leaving print empty. Here is the documentation for [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) and for [window.print()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this how to do it

```
$scope.openPrintPreview = function(countyId) {
    var printUrl = window.location.origin + '/#/print/' + countyId;
    var popupWin = window.open(printUrl.toString(), '_blank', 'width=800,height=700');

    setTimeout(function () {
        popupWin.print();
    }, 1000);
};
```